# python is not showing the windows install date

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, registry, winreg

Running on Windows 7 and Python 3.2.2, the following script can't give me the Windows installation date.

```
import winreg as reg
from datetime import datetime

key = reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion')
secs = reg.QueryValueEx(key, 'InstallDate')[0]
print(secs)
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(secs)
print(date)
```

output is always:

```
0
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

but when I search manually for the key with regedit, it contains the hex value 0x517c09e0 (1367083488 in decimal)

Comment: try printing out `secs` and `type(secs)`

Comment: `>>> secs
0
>>> type(secs)
<class 'int'>`

Comment: Clearly, the value there is wrong; how about `[1]` for index? (I don't have Windows to test)

Comment: it gives me the type of the value and the result is "4"

Comment: is you python 32 bit?

Comment: yes it is 32bit python on 64bit Windows 7

Comment: try adding `reg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY`

Comment: where should i do that ?

Comment: in your `OpenKey` at the end

Comment: same thing  output is :  0  1970-01-01 01:00:00

Comment: I don't have a windows machine to test but your issue is definitely using a 32 bit process. what does your key command look like

Comment: i didn't get you about saying "key command" but what's the point of my script if it does work on other computer because this issue ? and how programmers are fixing this compatibility problem please ?

Comment: I meant your OpenKey command.

Comment: key = reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion',0,reg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)

Comment: and the result now is : WindowsError: [Error 5] Accès refusé

Comment: try adding add `reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS`

Comment: unfortunately same output :  WindowsError: [Error 5] Accès refusé

Comment: do you have permissions to open the registry key?

Comment: of course I am working on an administrator account

Comment: last thing I can suggest use  `reg.KEY_READ | reg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY` and maybe `reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of `reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Comment: and finally this was helpful you saved my script thanx a lot , i've replaced reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS with reg.KEY_READ | reg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY and the output was :
1367083488
2013-04-27 18:24:48

Comment: we were in the last chance saloon there, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The registry access made by the 32-bit python process is getting redirected to a different registry hive on 64-bit Windows.

Even though your code specified access to `Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, it is actually getting redirected to `Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`

You likely want to specify `_winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY` or `_winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY` as the `sam` parameter to the `reg.OpenKey` function.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: i've tried both values and no result , how should i write this peace of code safely so I can run it on different variations of 32bit and 64bit of both python interpreter and Windows ?

Comment: `_winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY` would make a 64 bit application operate on  the 32-bit registry